# Save WMS layer directly on the server every day

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wms, php

I use PHP, PostGRES and GeoServer with OpenLayers and I have a WMS layer that is loaded from an external URL in GeoServer.

I would like to be able to somehow save the layer received from the external WMS on the server every day

If you understood the question, can you help me?

Comment: So you have a cascading WMS provided through GeoServer.  You want instead to harvest the images from this service, and then what? You want to provide the images as another WMS or tile service, or you just want to archive the images somehow?  Does the licence of the external WMS allow this?

Comment: #nmtoken I just want to save the wms content on the server for days so that I can play it back when needed from an archive.

Comment: you just need to make an http GET request each day using cron or scheduled tasks and save with a suitable name